# Can't push to heroku, sassc segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having trouble pushing to heroku, I've already tried others solutions related to *Precompiling assets failed.*, like modifing `application.rb` to disable precompiled assets, running `rake assets:precompile`, and updating to rails 6.3.1 to prevent mimemagic recent error.

Taking a look at heroku logs, I noticed:

> tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43:
> [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000        ruby 3.0.0p0
> (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]

Part of heroku's log

```
       ...
       yarn install v1.22.4
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 5.07s.
       /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
       ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]
       
       -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
       c:0042 p:---- s:0308 e:000307 CFUNC  :compile_data_context
       c:0041 p:0314 s:0303 e:000302 METHOD /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43
       c:0040 p:0044 s:0291 e:000290 METHOD /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29
       c:0039 p:0007 s:0285 e:000284 METHOD /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:30
       c:0038 p:0047 s:0280 e:000279 METHOD /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84
       c:0037 p:0014 s:0272 e:000271 BLOCK  /tmp/build_7857ebbd/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66 [FINISH]
       .....
       c:0036 p:---- s:0267 e:000266 CFUNC  :reverse_each
  7f104d3bd000-7f104d3be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
       7fffab4a6000-7fffac4a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
       7fffac503000-7fffac505000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
       7fffac505000-7fffac507000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
       ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
       
       
       Aborted
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a recent bug as reported in issue [133](https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/133) and [197](https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/197)

[One solution](https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/197#issuecomment-648889921) is to use an older sassc version. In particular, I've tried:

```
gem 'sassc', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.7.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.1.0 ' 
gem 'concurrent-ruby',  '~>1.1.5'
```

Which works just fine. All available versions are [listed here](https://rubygems.org/gems/sassc/versions)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the same thread, I found this solution more suitable than downgrading a bunch of gems.

Putting this at the top of your initializers/assets.rb enabled the assets to compile successfully

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.export_concurrent = false
end
```

Still a hack, but another option.

Source: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/197#issuecomment-735359755

Answer (score 2):

I've seen sassc segmentation fault errors before when upgrading between Ruby versions on heroku (in this case it was from Ruby 3.1.0 to 3.1.1). I recommend trying two things first:

1. Make sure you can precompile production assets locally `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`
2. Clear the Heroku build cache:

   - Install heroku-repo plugin `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo`
   - `heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname`
   - redeploy to Heroku